# unable to set up Windows HPC cluster correct on Azure

Tags: azure

I am setting up Windows HPC cluster according to the guide and sample code provided:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh560241(v=vs.85).aspx

The sample code has a Windows application to generate the cspkg and cscfg files. I can use these files to make the deployment on Azure successfully. But the problem is that the OS installed on the instance is Windows Server 2008 R2 rather than Windows Server 2008 R2 HPC Pack, which is defined in the csdef file in the following code. In addition, the config.EnableL2H() and config.EnableSOA() have also been invoked.

Is there something I did wrong when configuring the configuration files? Any suggestions will be appreciated. 
Thanks,

Hui

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem and fixed it. The problem is the fire wall issue between SQL Azure server and Azure instance deploying service. Windows HPC cluster reply on the SQL database to store the jobs history within HPC job scheduler. Without connecting to SQL server database, the process of staging the HPC pack module to Azure Blob fails.

The solution is to adjust the SQL Azure server fire wall filter management rules and check the box "enable communication between SQL server and the other Azure services".

Thank you,

Hui